# Scanning external jar for JPA entities when running spring-boot app in Intellij

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

Yesterday I had a problem where Hibernate couldn't find an external jar to scan for entities. I fixed that and it now works from the command line (and, more important,  in docker). However, when I try to run my spring-boot app inside Intellij, Hibernate cannot find the entity lib.

In my `persistence.xml`, I use the `jar-file` directive like so:
`<jar-file>BOOT-INF/lib/limina-1.0.jar<jar-file>`
and that works outside of Intellij but not inside. 
I've created a Spring-boot run configuration using the template available (I'm running Intellij Ultimate 2020-2) but it doesn't seem like it's running from the jar file but instead from the actual class files.

Somethings I could maybe do:

- Change the jar file path in `persistence.xml` and change it back when it comes to deployment.  I am uncertain what I should change it to but that can always be figured out.
- Use remote debugging. That is, however, not something I really want to do, it's a bit cumbersome.
- Something else.

I would be happy for any ideas here. I don't really want to go back to printf debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sidestepped the entire problem by determining exactly what entities where used and putting them in the `<class></class>` directive and removing the `<jar-file>` entirely.